# Для чего лучше использовать em, rem, % и px?

Tags: html, css, html5

Для каких элементов лучше использовать em, rem, %, и px и в каких случаях?
И что лучше использовать для той же ретины?
И какие плюсы и минусы,если можно в кратнце

Comment: `px` - для всех видов верстки и на все времена; `%` - верстка резиновых макетов; `rem` - адаптивная верстка, когда задается всему документу шрифт `html { font-size: 16px; }` и от него отталкиваются все размеры (1rem = 16px) , для `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { html { font-size: 12px; } ... ` соответственно на мобильных девайсах все дружно будет в меньших размерах, не придется для каждого переписывать размеры; `em` - то же самое что и `rem`, но размер зависит не от `html` , `body` а от родительского шрифта ....

Comment: https://webref.ru/course/css-basics/size, https://webref.ru/layout/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units

Comment: @HamSter, может стоило ответом?

Comment: @Grundy, нее, нужно более развернуто и красиво на ответ и для ретины я не знаю что лучше)

Answer (score 5):

**Если простыми словами:**

- `px` - для всех видов верстки и на все времена;
- `%` - для верстки резиновых макетов (`16px = 100%`);
- `rem` - для адаптивной верстки, когда задается всему
  документу шрифт

  `html { font-size: 16px; }` и от него отталкиваются
  все размеры (`1rem = 16px`) , 
  для `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { html { font-size: 12px; }` - соответственно на мобильных
  девайсах все дружно будет в меньших размерах, не придется для каждого
  переписывать размеры;
- `em` - то же самое что и `rem`, но размер зависит не от `html , body` а от шрифта родительского блока ( `1em = значению font-size родителя`).
- Есть еще `vw, vh` - современные единицы (`1vw = 1% от ширины окна`, `1vh = 1% от высоты окна`). Плюсы - шрифты масштабируются подобно svg с увеличением\уменьшением ширины экрана. Минусы - не всеми устр-вами и браузерами поддерживается [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Все единицы измерения обладают своими плюсами для своих нужд. Минусов для `px` не вижу, для относительных единиц `rem`,`em` - пересчет из пикселей (в макетах размеры в px, а нужно посчитать сколько это будет в относительных ед.).

Конкретно для ретина дисплеев единиц измерений к счастью нет, как и каких-то рекомендация\указаний. Тут действует тот же правило какой макет и верстка: резиновая, адаптивная, фиксированная.

**Почитать подробнее:**

1. [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.ru.html)
2. [webref.ru](https://webref.ru/css/value/size)
3. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
4. [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units)

**P.S:** Все зависит от личных предпочтений, любым из видов ед. измерений можно верстать любой макет, задавать размер шрифта и прочие размеры блоков.