# Почему так популярны относительные значения em/ почему абсолютные единицы ведут себя как относительные

Tags: html, css, html5, ui

1. Я из немного из другой сферы деятельности (архитектура) и заметил, что в веб разработке большинство использует относительные единицы измерения в `px`,`em`,когда речь идет о размере текста.

   Но во всех сферах проектирования чего-то для человека, во всех книгах и прочих источниках, используются значения в миллиметрах или дюймах. Все эргономические параметры рассчитываются относительно человека(в миллиметрах или дюймах).

   ***Так почему все используют какие то абстрактные единицы в px и тд., ведь они относятся к параметрам устройства (экрана), а не к антропометрическим параметрам человека?***

   Например к размерам его пальцев, или способности различать объект определенного размера на каком-то расстоянии, что удобнее измерять в привычных нам единицах -мм, дюймы?

2.Я попробовал ,для эксперимента, сделать квадрат размером `30mm` указав ему значения `height` и `width` и померить его размеры линейкой:

- 1.На мониторе с разрешением 1920х1080 размер квадрата 29 мм
- 2.На ноутбуке 1366×768 размер квадрата 28 мм
- 3.На смартфоне 780х1280 размер квадрата 7 мм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***То есть как видно абсолютные значения в `mm` работают как и относительные значения в `px` и зависят от плотности пикселей, почему это происходит?***

***Как сделать так чтобы на всех устройствах отображались точные значения в `mm`?***

При этом если я начерчу квадрат 30х30 в любом CAD в масштабе 1:1 он будет точно соответствовать этому размеру на мониторе.

Comment: Во-первых, потому что по стандарту определение миллиметров выводится из тех же пикселей. Во-вторых, потому что размеры должны зависеть от расстояния от глаз до экрана: квадрат на экране телефона обязан быть меньше, а квадрат на экране 4K-телевизора обязан быть больше, иначе пользователь его просто не разглядит. Браузер обычно автоматически масштабирует страницу под характеристики текущего устройства вывода.

Comment: @andreymal  так какой смысл тогда в абсолютных значениях? если они и не абсолютные вовсе

Comment: @andreymal то о чем вы говорите это и есть концепция пикселей,но причем тут mm, как то не логично

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-em-rem-%d0%b8-px

Comment: Возможно, потому что в вебе все делается для отображения на экранах - монитор, телефон, телевизор. А в архитектуре, инженерии и т.п. для каких-то физически осязаемых вещей. И так как для экранов основной единицей измерения является пиксель, то и в разработке веб-чего-либо используются именно они, а во всех сферах проектирования чего-то для человека и используются "привычные нам единицы мм и дюймы".

Comment: @fanfer так веб придуман человеком, для человека, не для мониторов же)))

Comment: @ПоляковРоман но всю информацию с веба человек воспринимает с монитора)

[ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units)

"В реальной жизни сантиметр – это эталон длины, одна сотая метра. А пиксель может быть разным, в зависимости от экрана.

Но в формулах выше под пикселем понимается «сферический пиксель в вакууме», точка на «стандартизованном экране», характеристики которого описаны в спецификации.

Поэтому ни о каком соответствии cm реальному сантиметру здесь нет и речи. Это полностью синтетическая и производная единица измерения, которая не нужна."

Comment: @fanfer тогда всё ещё остаётся вопрос, нахрена этот сантиметр вообще изобрели в CSS

Comment: @fanfer плюсую, сам в недоумении

Comment: возможно, потому что на момент его создание не было такого разнообразия размеров и разрешений экранов как сейчас. тогда была возможность создать стандарт 1см = 38рх. сейчас с разрешением 1280рх по ширине, условно, может быть лептоп с диагональю 17 дюймов, а может быть телефон с диагональю 7 дюймов

Comment: @fanfer да, очень сложно понять смыл такой единицы измерения

Comment: @ПоляковРоман печально

Comment: @fanfer смысл, если у нее нет стандартизированного значения,это и не единица измерения тогда

Comment: @ПоляковРоман даже не знаю как с этим жить теперь

Comment: @fanfer я тоже думаю что это заговор и мы все умрем)